Django custom model queryset returns fields dynamically
I have a few models that are translatable.
The way we implemented it was: for each translatable model, there is a ModelTranslation model.
E.g. for the Car model exists a CarTranslation model with FK to Car.
The translation models also have as fields: the language, and any text/char fields of the original model.
E.g. if the Car model looks like this
class Car(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  description = models.TextField()

the CarTranslation then looks like this:
class CarTranslation(models.Model):
  car = models.ForeignKey(to=Car)
  language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
  name = models.CharField()
  description = models.TextField()

In views that return translatable data, we check what language the user has defined: if it's english (the default) we return Car as it is; if it's not english, we return the translated data in CarTranslation for the user language (if it exists, otherwise default to english).
We have an old implementation of this that I want to improve: right now we add the translations in the serializer context and then, in the serializer, we check if there are translations, otherwise return the default.
But I don't like this.
I think a much better solution would be using custom model managers/querysets.
I'm trying this:
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
from django.db.models import F, Subquery

class CarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
  def with_translation(self, language):
    from cars.models import CarTranslation

    if language == "en":
      return self
    translation_query = CarTranslation.objects.filter(language=language, car=OuterRef("pk"))
    return self.annotate(
      name=Coalesce(Subquery(translation_query.values("name")[:1]), F("name")),
      description=Coalesce(Subquery(translation_query.values("description")[:1]), F("description")),
    )

And then use it in the views like this:
class CarView(ListAPIView):
  def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    language = user.language
    return Car.objects.with_translation(language)

But it produces this error: ValueError: The annotation 'name' conflicts with a field on the model.
I've also tried annotating with a different name, then not selecting the conflicting columns and returning the annotated values instead:
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
from django.db.models import F, Subquery

class CarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
  def with_translation(self, language):
    from cars.models import CarTranslation

    if language == "en":
      return self
    translation_query = CarTranslation.objects.filter(language=language, car==OuterRef("pk"))
    queryset = self.annotate(
      translated_name=Coalesce(Subquery(translation_query.values("name")[:1]), F("name")),
      translated_description=Coalesce(Subquery(translation_query.values("description")[:1]), F("description")),
    )

    return queryset.values(
      *[field.name for field in self.model._meta.fields if field.name not in ["name", "description"]]
      name=F("translated_name"),
      description=F("translated_description"),
    )

but it produces the same exact error.
Any idea how I can return either the default or the translated value from the custom queryset?

What is car==OuterRef("pk"), shouldn't this be car=OuterRef("pk")?

Why does Car has a name field if you derive it from CarTranslation?

It's a typo.
I didn't copy the code here as it is, so there may be typos.

Car has the defaults in english.
We only use CarTranslation if the user language is other than english.

You can not work with the name of a field that already exists, this could also result in a lot of name clashes, and behavior that is not ambiguous for the runtime environment, but makes it very complicated for the programmer.
from django.db.models import F, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


class CarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_translation(self, language):
        from cars.models import CarTranslation

        if language == 'en':
            return self.annotate(custom_name=F('name'), custom_description=F('description'))
        translation_query = CarTranslation.objects.filter(
            language=language, car_id=OuterRef('pk')
        )
        return self.annotate(
            custom_name=Coalesce(
                Subquery(translation_query.values('name')[:1]), F('name')
            ),
            custom_description=Coalesce(
                Subquery(translation_query.values('description')[:1]),
                F('description'),
            ),
        )
Then in the serializer, we can use the custom_name and custom_description:
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='custom_name')
    description = serializers.CharField(source='custom_description')

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['name', 'description']

Ideally I wouldn't want to make the serializers depend on whether we chose to translate the queryset or not.  I.e. if we use the same serializer in a view where we don't use with_translation in the queryset, this breaks. It's unlikely that we'll have such case, but I'm not comfortable with having this dependency.

@MarcoCastanho: well if I recall correctly there was a package to make fields translatable, that thus puts the logic in the field, so it fetches the name from a translation column (so name_fr, name_de, etc.) based on the language injected, so then you move the logic to the field, which makes it easier and more transparent.
